# Problem With .ipynb files not running in Batch selection. (failed to create process.)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pywinauto

I Downgraded the python version from 3.8.1 to 3.7.4 so that pywinauto can work in Batch files. The command which was working earlier is not working now.

The command I am using to run .ipynb file is:

```
runipy VPN_Automate_V1.ipynb, 
now I am facing: 
failed to create process.
```

**NOTE:** The script is working fine when I run through jupyter notebook, but unable to trigger the same in command prompt, our project requirement is to run the script through command prompt.

Comment: Hi All,
I found that Python.exe file is missing in path: C:\Python38\python.exe, which was being accessed by Command Prompt. Now I am able to run the script.

Comment: Command **runipy <mynotebookfile>.ipynb** was not showing the file path, instead I used command: **jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute <MyNotebook>.ipynb**

Answer (score 1):

I found that Python.exe file is missing in path: C:\Python38\python.exe, which was being accessed by Command Prompt. Now I am able to run the script. 
Command: **runipy .ipynb** was not showing the file path, instead I used command: **jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute .ipynb**